# Can someone double check my PCB?

Tags: pcb-design, ac, dc

This is my first 'real' PCB, since it also contains AC power together with a bit of DC it would be awesome if someone could check my design.

Description:

I'm building the MPCNC project and would love to connect all my devices / switches to a single pcb. The pcb will be powered by AC 230v and will reroute the power to different screw terminals through some 12v relays. I will be converting 12v from the 230v mains. Max current that will be 15A.

After my initial research I kept into account the following:

- added enough fuses
- all components are rated for the required current / voltage
- trace width high enough for max 35C temp rise
- kept Live and Neutral traces on different planes
- created a copper pour on the top plane (disabled on the image to more clearly show the traces but you can see the red dash outline)
- kept the 12v traces far enough away from the 230v traces
- user clearance of 4mm for the copper pour to account for creepage
- between 2 live traces where the distance was shorter I added a slot to prevent creepage

Should I do a ground pour on the bottom plane as well? If so, do I connect them through vias or through the ground terminal of my source terminal?

Already want to thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT: after the comments below I made the following changes.

- Added flyback diodes to the coils of the relays
- copper poured both sides for ground plane and connected both top and bottom ground plane to the ground terminal of the incomming source power

EDIT#2:

- Added slots in between all the AC screw terminal ports for extra safety.
- Increased the clearance in the top ground plane to 4.5

I'll be getting this produced soon after the last changes and a final double check from my side.

Thanks to @RonBeyer @rdtsc @Andyaka @le_top for the feedback, it's really appreciated!

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you done a design rule check on clearances? Is 4mm enough? No diodes across the relay coils? Do you really need a GND plane? Is GND actually protective earth?

Comment: I'd copper-pour both sides of the PCB.  Generally they should be ground or chassis ground, but could be no-net as long as they won't radiate or couple interference. For no other reason than it will require less etchant to manufacture, resulting in less waste.

Comment: How much current is the 12V supply generating?  The 12V traces may need to be wider.

Comment: @Andyaka 4mm should be enough for the worst condition creepage at 230v according to the calculators I used. GND is connected to protective earth. I did not know a diode was required along the relay coil, I'll look into that.

Comment: Why is there nothing routed to the coil side of your relay? (and yes, it needs a diode) (EDIT: Nevermind about the coil comment, I see the *very thin* traces, might want to think about making them bigger).

Comment: @rdtsc 420ma, the trace is 0.4mm wide. Do I then connect both planes through vias or through the ground terminal on my source connector?

Comment: @RonBeyer the trace is 0.4mm wide, I used a calculator for this, can increase it if needed.

Comment: Doesn't hurt to have it a little bigger. Please add the diode though.

Comment: @RonBeyer 0.4mm is 15mils, according to my calculator again :D For the diode, I just add it in parallel to the coil?

Comment: Using a creepage calculator is a good initiative, but there are regulations too.  I use 5 mm  on my boards - the actual distance depends on the board type, etc.  You can also add a slot.  You could improve your planes by adjusting placement and routing.